# Real time edit sliding html menu

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, innerhtml, slidedown

I'm using a sliding menu (select/object html one), which is generated dynamically by taking data from a DB, using a jsp page.

I also have an input text field, where I can search things from the sliding menu. I want to write the root of a word that is contained in my menu, and my menu must "resize" showing all the items with the root that I've wrote, and only those ones.

I can't use server side operations (like sending data via post) but I need to solve this client side (because I need this result immediately).

I've actually solved this issue using javascript, but I have some performance problems with this solution, because i have to use IE 8.

Is there any similar solution using JQuery or Ajax?

Here is something similar to my code:

HTML:

```
<select multiple id="testSelect">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>temp</option>
    <option>cast</option>
    <option>dest</option>
    <option>inst</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="searhSelect(this)" />​
```

searhSelect function will be called on each key press (when user release a key actually) and will filter #testSelect object.

JS:

```
var optionsList;
function searhSelect(el) {
    var select = document.getElementById('testSelect');
    if(!optionsList) {        
        optionsList = select.cloneNode(true);  //copy select to a variable for future use      
    }
    select.innerHTML = "";//remove all options.

    for(var i =0; i < optionsList.options.length; i++) {
        var opt = optionsList.options[i];
        if(opt.innerHTML.indexOf(el.value) != -1) {
            select.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How many elements do you have? In that searchSelect cloned DOM element is used. Possibly storing items in regular JS array will help.

Comment: I guess more then 10k elements. When I start typing it takes like 20 seconds to end the task. How can I store my elements into a regular JS array? Unfortunately I'm not that "smart" on JS...

Comment: Hm... 10k elements? That is a lot. Do not think that even JS array will actually help... AJAX may help, but once you will try to show large amount of items - it will be slow anyway(because of slow dom update).

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. Those performances are only in old versions of IE, on Chrome is really faster. Thank you for your tips by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code like this:

```
var optionsList = [];
function searhSelect(el) {
    var select = document.getElementById('testSelect');

    if(optionsList.length == 0) {        
        for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++)
            optionsList[i] = {key:select.options[i].value,value:select.options[i].innerHTML}; //copy select to a variable for future use      
    }   
    //if(el.value.length > 2) {
        var tmp = "<select id=\"testSelect\" mulitple=\"multiple\" size=\"4\">";
        for(var i =0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
            var opt = optionsList[i];
            if(opt.value.indexOf(el.value) != -1) {                 
                tmp += ' <option value="' + opt.key + '" >' + opt.value + '</option> ';                        
            }         
        }   
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = tmp + "</select>";
    //}

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
   <select multiple id="testSelect">
      <option>test</option>
      <option>temp</option>
      <option>cast</option>
      <option>dest</option>
      <option>inst</option>
      <!-- in my test same options you see above were copy/pasted many times. I had little more than 10k  options->
   </select>
</div>
```

I've removed all clone/appendChild, pusshed all elements int array with object containing value and text fields and, what is the most important, options are now created with innerHTML. Also, please note that select is now wrapped with another div. And instead of using innerHTML of select and simply setting options HTML, string with whole select HTML is created (`var tmp = "<select id=\"testSelect\" mulitple=\"multiple\" size=\"4\">";`). That is needed as a workaround for [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228/en-us) bug of IE.

In your current implementation each option is added once it is found, one by one. That way IE will render element each time new option is added (). But code above will force render only once - when all options are defined. Unfortunatelly, that helps only partially. It works faster than code from question, but it still takes around 10s (comparing to 20-30s with old code) to render new select element (`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = tmp + "</select>";` - at this point it is freezing browser for 10s)

I do no think you can make it faster without making some global changes (custom multiple select with checkboxes to select an element, for instance, and elements being shown/hidden with display:block/none). Possible solution - update element only when there will be relatively small amount of filtered elements. For instance - when length of value to search is more than 2 characters (see commented out `//if(el.value.length > 2) {`). But to use it, current implementation require additional coding (at least, full list should be shown again once user remove some characters from input field).

Comment: Thank your for your functionaly and detailed answer. I've tried your code, but it takes at least the same time as mine (about 10 seconds). Too bad, I guess we should "deal" with IE8 performance...

Comment: You can try to build your own "select". Just a div with list of other item divs inside. Item div contains checkbox (so you can submit selected items) and text Actually, you can hide checkbox and completely mimick select behavior (just handle clicks on text and set checkboxes checked/not checked). And modify code to show/hide elements with style.display  property. That should be faster, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to do something like autocomplete. Have you tried http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete?

Or do you simply want the SELECT options to be filtered out? Then I guess it is easier to hide/disabled them instead of cloning them.

Comment: I don't want to autocomplete. When i'm writing in the text box, my list will automatically "resize" with only values that contains my typed text. And when I delete some text, my list automatically resize to The original length.